# How to make iOS keyboard appear/stay up during entire app lifecycle?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, keyboard, storyboard

I want to know how to make the keyboard appear in an iOS Swift app and remain there permanently.  I know it appears when the user touches inside a textfield.  That's not what I want.  I want it to be there when the user loads up the app and to stay there permanently.  I do still want the keyboard to communicate with a textfield as it normally would.

I would also like to be able to use the keyboard in storyboard auto layout and scale/align my buttons around the keyboard, which is asked here:
[Xcode storyboard layout size simulation - keyboard up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48546560/xcode-storyboard-layout-size-simulation-keyboard-up)

**What I tried:**

If I could simulate a "touch" inside a textfield programmatically I think I can accomplish my task.  I would forcibly simulate a "touch" once the app loads and then in the "textFieldShouldReturn" method I can repeat the forced programmatic touch inside the textfield to prevent the keyboard from disappearing.  (This may cause the keyboard to disappear and then reappear quickly, which would be ugly and undesirable.)  How do I force this fake touch?

**In Conclusion:**

I am using iOS Storyboard and Swift.

How do I cause a keyboard to load up on start up and remain there even after pressing return/send?

If the above is impossible, how do I programattically force a touch inside a textfield?

Comment: Sounds like you want to develop a Blackberry app :-)

Comment: maybe you got your own reason to do so, but for me I feel it is very annoying for a keyboard to be appear there all the time. Simply just my opinion.

Comment: @NicolasMiari I agree with you.You can add custom keyboard view on window.It won't dismiss.But I don't think Apple will permit a 'Blackberry' app.

Comment: If it's any help, the keyboard typically hides because the text field the user was editing resigns first responder status. Perhaps you can keep the keyboard on screen by implementing the text field delegate methods.

Comment: @NicolasMiari I don't think keyboard will keep for a text field not on screen.

Comment: Oh, I missed that part. Wonder what's the purpose of a keyboard, then

Comment: Can you explain why do you want the keyboard to stay? Might there are alternate solutions for this.

Comment: @AmritSidhu It is a customer request.  I was given a layout of how they want their messaging app to look and the layout includes the keyboard on screen.  They'd have to redo the art/buttons, or come up with something else to fill the space if I have the keyboard disappear.  They've made it clear they don't want to do that.

Comment: That's really sad to hear. Sometimes customers ask the most ridiculous things, and for the most ridiculous reasons. Ask a graphic/web designer if you don't believe me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can't do this from storyboard side, but from code side, assuming that you name your textfield "textField", you can do `self.textField.becomeFirstResponder()` on your `viewDidLoad()` in order to make the keyboard appear when you enter on this screen. This should keep the keyboard on screen unless you do `resignFirstResponder()` elsewhere.