# Xcode storyboard layout size simulation - keyboard up?

Tags: xcode, autolayout, interface-builder

You can click on these buttons in Interface Builder:

[image: "View as:" options in Interface Builder]

to change the size of the view controller you are working on, and the autolayout solver solves it there and then.

So obviously you can check the layout on various size screens.

Surely, there's a function somewhere that makes the "keyboard appear".

How can I show the keyboard, or allow for the keyboard area, on a Storyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **no such function** in Xcode 9.

However, you can provide a custom freeform size for your view controllers to simulate a keyboard appearance.

1. Select a view controller and click on the Size Inspector on the right sidebar (the fifth icon from the left).
2. Select **Freeform** for **Size** in the **View Controller** section.
3. Enter a size of your choice. [You can calculate with a general keyboard height of **216**.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11284321/3151675)

[image: Simulated Size option for view controller]

Comment: Good to know the answer is No!  So the only way is just free-form it yourself.  Nice one!